# Bash equivalent to python "unicodedata.name"?

Tags: bash, unicode

is there an equivalent to python "unicodedata.name" in bash, maybe a linux file with letter names? Is it possible to convert an "L" to "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L" with iconv?

Thanks for help

```
import unicodedata; print (unicodedata.name("L"))
```

If an equivalent in iconv exists I don't know which is the right one. Wanted instead of "L" as issue "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L".

```
echo -e "L" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UNICODELITTLE//TRANSLIT
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `perl` one-liner:

```sh
$ perl -CA -Mcharnames=\(\) -E 'say charnames::viacode(ord $ARGV[0])' L
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
```

Or with `python`:

```sh
$ python3 -c 'import sys, unicodedata; print(unicodedata.name(sys.argv[1][0]))' L
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
```